# Error: pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an HTMLImageElement

Tags: javascript, angular, tensor, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

Trying to predict with TensorflowJS. But, in input image above error is showing? My image is **Uint8Array** type. How can I pass an Uint8Array type for making a tensor?

```
    
      async predict(imageData: any) {
    
        let img = tf.browser.fromPixels(imageData, 3).resizeBilinear([256, 256]) # problem showing here
        img = imageData.reshape([256, 256, 3])
        img = tf.cast(img, 'float32')
    
        const segmentation = this.model.predict(img) as any
    
        console.log('success')
    
      }
    
    
    loadImage(file: FileList) {
    
        this.fileToUpload = file.item(0);
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
    
        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
          this.imageUrl = reader.result
          this.predict(this.convertDataURIToBinary(this.imageUrl)); # passing Unit8Array image from here
        }
    
      }
```

Any idea how can I overcome it? Thanks for your suggestion.

**Update**

Solved this issue using '@ViewChild('ImageRef') ImageRef: ElementRef;' . Lastly I converted Unit8Array into imageData then drew into canvas with putImageData.

But facing problem in another part. As I am doing image segmentation, the result is just the inverse of what I made in python. Any idea?

In python I did - >

```
    img_face = cv2.resize(frame,(256,256))
    img_face = cv2.cvtColor(img_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_face = img_face / 255.0
    img_face = img_face.astype(np.float32)
    mask = model.predict(np.expand_dims(img_face , axis=0))[0]
```

And my current js part is already mentioned above as predict() func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `imageData` is a UInt8Array, it can be easily converted to a tensor using `tf.tensor`

```
tf.tensor(imageData)
```

Additionnally the image width and height can be specified while creating the tensor

```
tf.tensor(imageData, [height, width, channels])
```

Now regarding the image processing, in python you are doing

```
img_face / 255.0
```

You are not doing the same thing in js. you need to divide the js tensor by 255

Comment: In this case its showing while used >> let img = tf.tensor(imageData, [256, 256, -1]) ->  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Tensor must have a shape comprised of positive integers but got shape [256,256,-1] also tried with [256,256, 3] but another error happed.

Comment: Anyway, I solved that issue using @ViewChild (directly using the image from Html). But After model prediction, I have an image object tensor(added it EDIT ques part). Any idea how can I show it to HTML as an image?

Comment: In that case image is not an UInt8Array as you said, it is rather an HtmlElement.

Comment: If you want to render the tensor to an image, you can use `tf.browser.toPixels`

Comment: Uint8Array(50424) [ 255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, … ] was my array. Anyway after using tf.browser.toPixels its showing >> Uncaught (in promise) Error: toPixels only supports rank 2 or 3 tensors, got rank 4.  My tensor array shape was [1,256,256,1]. How to reduce rank here for making 4 to 3 ? ! Thanks

Comment: You need to choose the height and width such as h * w * channel = 50424. Something like `tf.tensor(imageData, [191, 88, 3])` will work. You can squeeze your first dimension tensor.squeeze() or reshape it with tensor.reshape([256, 256, 1]) and use the new tensor returned

Comment: After applying all this staff now I have - > Uint8ClampedArray(262144) [ 0, 0, 0, 255, ...]
Tried the canvas - > this.context.drawImage(unit_8_array, 0, 0) but unable to generate base64 with "toDataURL" As my main goal was to view it on HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235091/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-msi).